# Regarding the recursive mapping of Vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Here is the code that is a practice for writing vim plugin. I write it as per the vim docs: `:help usr_41.txt` section 41.11 write a plugin.

```
let s:save_cpo = &cpo
set cpo&vim

if exists("g:loaded_echoplugin")
  finish
endif

function s:EchoWord()
  echo expand('<cword>')
endfunction

if !exists(":EchoWord")
  command -nargs=0 EchoWord :call s:EchoWord()
endif

if !hasmapto('<Plug>EchoWord')
  map <F8> <Plug>EchoWord
endif

noremap <script> <Plug>EchoWord <SID>EchoWord
noremap <SID>EchoWord :call <SID>EchoWord()<CR>

let g:loaded_echoplugin = 1

let &cpo = s:save_cpo
unlet s:save_cpo
```

The code is for displaying the word under the cursor when clicking `<F8>`. Here is the mapping sequence: `<F8> -> <Plug>EchoWord -> <SID>EchoWord -> :call <SID>Echoword()` and it works.

Here, however, I have 2 questions:
1. I have used the `noremap` here, why it is still able to **remap** or **recursive mapping**?
2. If I change the mapping from `map <F8> <Plug>EchoWord` to `noremap <F8> <Plug>EchoWord`, it will do **NOT** work.

Could anybody please help to figure it out? thanks!

Answer (score 7):

`<Plug>Foo` is a mapping. Whether it is itself recursive or not doesn't matter.

When you do a recursive mapping, Vim uses *whatever is the current meaning of the commands in the right hand side:*

```
map b B
map <key> db        " works like dB
```

When you do a non-recursive mapping, Vim uses *the original meaning of the commands in the right hand side:*

```
map b B
noremap <key> db    " works like db
```

`<Plug>Foo` doesn't mean anything by default so there's no point mapping it non-recursively.

You *want* recursiveness, here, so you are supposed to use `map`, `imap`, `nmap`, etc.

Comment: Shouldn't that read `noremap <key> db` in your second code block?

Comment: Thank you @MichaelHärtl. You are the first to notice (or notice AND report) this in six years.

Answer (score 1):

I have read the vim docs for the related command carefully, and I have found the root cause. I add it here just for anybody who may concern.

Type the command `:help :map-<script>` and here is the reason:

```
Note: ":map <script>" and ":noremap <script>" do the same thing.  The
"<script>" overrules the command name.  Using ":noremap <script>" is
preferred, because it's clearer that remapping is (mostly) disabled.
```